# install PPKG files silently in windows 10 Mobile

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

Currently only way i found for installing PPKG file on Windows phone 10 is plugging the device with system and then click on PPKG file.
But need some way that user need not to do anything. Is there any way or any tool which can do silent PPKG installation in Windows phone 10?

Is InstallationManager will help for installing PPKG file?
Link for InstallationManager
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.phone.management.deployment.installationmanager

Comment: I don't know anything about ppkg format you talk about but in my searches I found this . hope to be helpful
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/NfcProvisioner/cs/Scenario1.xaml.cs

Comment: look if [IUTool.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn789233(v=vs.85).aspx) works.